# Multiples effects in dialog show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Using dialog it is possible multiples effects at same time? For example, in show, bounce and highlight.

I tried `{effect: 'bounce', duration: 550, effect: 'highlight', duration: 550},` but only the last effect runs.

```
$('.modal').click(function () {
    $(".dialog-modal").dialog({
        modal: true,
        hide: "fadeOut",
        show: {effect: 'bounce', duration: 550, effect: 'highlight', duration: 550},
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What you are passing is an object, so you are overwritting effect with the second `effect: 'highlight'`

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time I just spent on this makes 0 sense.  And I still didn't get the result I wanted.

But this should at least help you on your way.  [Check da fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY2VS/1/)

### jQueryUI:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $dlg = $('.dialog-modal');
    var $mdl = $('.modal');
    $dlg.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'sweetums',
        hide: "fadeOut",
        show: {
            effect: 'bounce',
            duration: 550
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $dlg.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    var $newDialog = $('.sweetums');
    $mdl.click(function () {
        $dlg.dialog('open');
        $newDialog.effect("highlight", 550);
    });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<button class="modal">Click</button>
<div class="dialog-modal">some stuff</div>
```

If you're wondering why I made a second object for `$newDialog` it's because the old one was originally a div and text but when the modal is made, it expands and adds buttons.  `$dlg` would only do the effect on the text itself and not the box as a whole, so wrapping the whole thing was necessary.